# Accessing arguments with argv

Tags: c, argv

This is something I've been testing by just printing out a bunch of stuff, but there's one case I can't quite figure out for some reason.

I need to pass an integer as an argument to a function to be used later, but when I print it back out again to make sure I stored it correctly, I get a random number. This is the relevant part of the code:

```
int num_bytes = argv[1]; 
....
printf("Max number of bytes: %d", num_bytes);
```

I only passed one argument to the function, which was an int. I also tried casting argv[1] as an int, but that didn't work either. I'm not sure if this is an issue with the printf or not. If it's just that, I don't mind. I just needed to know I stored the value as an int properly. I know that argv is an array of pointers to strings (C strings I think?) but I thought you could cast characters to ints.

Answer (score 5):

`char **argv` is considered an array of characters (or a string).  You'll need to convert the value inside of `argv` to an integer first.

You can do this through `atoi`:

```
int num_bytes = atoi(argv[1]);
```

Comment: atoi() is not a standard function, see my answer.

Comment: @H2CO3: You're required to import `<stdlib.h>` for both methods, regardless.  `atoi()` is the more straightforward (and easier to observe) way.

Comment: I'm wondering why your answer gets two upvotes and mine zero, where I provide multiple solutions along with a *standard* one, and I also explain the reason why it's producing these particular results...

Comment: Define "standard".  I'm a bit perplexed that you would insist that one method is a standard over the other, despite both doing similar things, and both requiring the same library to be imported.  Although I would wager that `atoi()` is more straightforward, since it only requires the `char *s` argument.

Comment: standard: found in either of the official C papers (ANSI C, C89, C99 etc.)

Comment: @H2CO3: `atoi()` is a standard c library function and is defined under §7.22.1.2 of c99 standard.

Answer (score 0):

argv is a pointer to an array of strings. You need to call atoi(argv[1]) to get the integer argument that you passed.